# fields of HyperlinkEvent instance is NULL when invoke hyperlinkUpdate method in HyperlinkListener

Tags: java

I try to add a `hyperlinkLabel` in panel ,and open the url in chrome when I click the `hyperlinklabel` . But it does not work.

Here is my java code:

```
    String hyperlinkText = "this is <a href=\"http://www.baidu.com\">baidu</a>";
    hyperlinkLabel.setHyperlinkText(hyperlinkText);

    HyperlinkListener hyperlinkListener = new HyperlinkListener() {
        @Override
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            HyperlinkFrame.this.dealListener(e);
        }
    };
    hyperlinkLabel.addHyperlinkListener(hyperlinkListener);
```

and the dealListener method is :

```
private void dealListener(HyperlinkEvent e)
{
    if(e.getEventType() != HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)
        return;

    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When debugging , it throws a `NullPointerException` . And almost all the fields in `HyperlinkEvent` instance are null , I don't know how to fix it.Do I miss something?

Comment: If use `JEditorPane` instead of `HyperlinkLabel` , It will work well